# I am adding datetime using daterangepicker in my rails application but not updated as parameter datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am adding date-time using date-range-picker in my rails application, But when we create or update date-time is updated on server but +6 hour extra.

Added in my configuration file: `config.time_zone = "Mexico City"`

for select daterange:

```
    $('#ordenes_servicio_OS_FECHAASIGNACION, \
    #ordenes_servicio_OS_FECHALLEGADA, \
    #ordenes_servicio_OS_FECHAINCIO, \
    #ordenes_servicio_OS_FECHAFIN, \
    #ordenes_servicio_OS_FECHATERMINO').daterangepicker({
             "singleDatePicker": true,
             "timePicker": true,
             "timePickerSeconds": true,
             "autoApply": true,
             "locale": {
                 "format": "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss A",
                 "separator": " - ",
                 "fromLabel": "From",
                 "toLabel": "To",
                 "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
                 "weekLabel": "W",
                 "daysOfWeek": [ "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa" ],
                 "monthNames": [
                     "January",
                     "February",
                     "March",
                     "April",
                     "May",
                     "June",
                     "July",
                     "August",
                     "September",
                     "October",
                     "November",
                     "December"
                 ],
                 "firstDay": 1
             },
             "showCustomRangeLabel": false,

             "opens": "center"
           });
```

Parameter from params =

```
"OS_FECHAASIGNACION"=>"20/04/2018 6:53:08 AM"
```

Update query:

```
UPDATE `ordenes_servicios` SET `OS_FECHAASIGNACION` = '2018-04-20 11:53:08', `updated_at` = '2018-04-03 05:57:30' WHERE `ordenes_servicios`.`ID` = 5
```

Please Give me exact answer, How can we update datetime as utc-6 to server? As we set from parameter.

Comment: What if you fetch it back from database? What does it show, 06:53 OR 11:53?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh
When I fetched from database data is show as i have set like 06:53

Answer (score 0):

To fix the time in database, such that it will always dealt with UTC, you can set the following.

config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc

config.active_record.default_timezone determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc.

Comment: I believe, it is from the contents of /etc/timezone file in your server. 

To match your rails time with server time you can use it as follows:

config.time_zone = File.read("/etc/timezone").chomp

Comment: @sawmiya Getting Same result